# Multisite setup creating custom table

Tags: multisite, database

If I'm running a multi-site setup and I create a new table and add it to the WordPress database, will it be accessible to all sites or is it created to be site specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you.

Normally when you create and query a table you use the `$wpdb->prefix` property as part of the table name. In a multisite install this prefix includes the current site ID. So if you use `dbDelta()` to create a table with the name `$wpdb->prefix . 'tablename'`, then — assuming the default prefix of `wp_` — this table will be created as `wp_2_tablename`, and `wp_3_tablename` etc. This ultimately means that each site in the network gets its own copy of the table, and you query the current site's table with `$wpdb->prefix . 'tablename'`.

However, if you want a single table shared across the network, then you should create and query it with `$wpdb->base_prefix`, which will be the same on all sites (`wp_`, if you use the default). That way if you query it with `$wpdb->base_prefix . 'tablename'` the same table will be queried regardless of which site you're currently on.